# SAS - I want to group by year, age, and county. My year variable is in format of datemonthyear, and so my sum by groups is not working as exptected

Tags: sql, sas, proc

SAS - I want to group by year, age, and county. My year variable is in format of datemonthyear, and so my sum by groups is not working as expected.

I have 4 variables in the input data:

1. Age, which is listed as "1-55", "56-65"
2. Date, which has values like "01Jan2019"
3. County, which has values like 1001
4. Disease, which has numeric values (1-1000)

I want a table has the sum of disease by age, county and year (as a year not by date) like this:

| Age | Year | County | Sum_of Disease |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-55 | 2019 | 1001. | 52000 |

But instead I am getting repeating years for the same county and age group.

This is my code:

```
    proc sql;
    create table outlib.sum as
    select age, county, year(date) as year,
    sum(disease) as sum_disease
    from inlib.data
    where age = "1-55" or age = "56-64"
    group by age, county, year(date);
    quit;
```

Comment: Could you give some sample data?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get that, actually. Your syntax looks correct. However, you could try to change your grouping to `GROUP BY age, county, CALCULATED year` and see if that works.

Comment: The age variable is probably formatted.  Try using Proc MEANS to aggregate.  The proc will group by formatted values.  In SQL select min(age) as age and group by put(age,agefmt.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems SAS does not recognize the `year(Date)` from the `select` statement in the `group by` so it remerges summary statistics back with the original data.

Instead, use `CALCULATED year` in the `group by`.

Test data to replicate:

```
DATA data;
    INPUT age $ Date :Date9. County Disease;
    FORMAT Date Date9.;
    CARDS;
1-55 01Jan2019 1001 998
56-65 01Jan2019 1001 2
1-55 01Jan2019 1000 1
1-55 28Feb2019 1001 500
1-55 20Oct2021 1001 500
1-55 20Oct2021 1000 501
56-65 20Oct2021 1000 2
;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE sum AS
    SELECT
        age,
        County,
        YEAR(Date) AS year,
        SUM(Disease) AS sum_disease
    FROM data
    WHERE age IN ("1-55" "56-65")
    GROUP BY
        age,
        County,
        CALCULATED year
    ;
QUIT;
```